# configurar sql express

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cuando se instala sql express en un servidor y en la misma red tengo una maquina cliente con el cual quiero ingresar al motor de bd pero no puedo, anteriormente me habian comentado que el sql express hay realizar un configuracion pero la verdad no se que configuracion.

Comment: describe tu red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para que puedas conectarte con otra pc, cuando instales pon el modo de autenticación en mixto y le creas un usuario, luego asegurate de tener estas opciones configuradas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo más habitual es entrar al SQL Server a través de una red utilizando el protocolo TCP/IP.

El SQL Express instala por defecto el protocolo deshabilitado, por lo que debes habilitarlo.

En Windows 10,

- ve a las herramientas administrativas del panel de control
- entra a la administración de equipos
- Servicios y aplicaciones
- SQL Server configuration manager
- SQL Server Network Configuration
- Protocols for *el nombre de tu instancia*
- busca TCP/IP en el panel derecho, habilitalo y listo.

Además, puedes ajustar en las propiedades por cuales de las interfaces de red se estará a la escucha y el puerto (por defecto el puerto es el 1433).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otras versiones de Windows, busca el *SQL Server configuration manager* en el menú inicio.